# Nothing happen after payment success on android billing activity

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm working on android anjlab in app purchasing.When a user attempts to make a purchase it is successful but code is not.Its success when user click again after purchasing.But they have to do that for a reason for activated to vip status.And i don't want to work like this.Steps work's as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906980/in-app-billing-issue) And [here](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/199)

[Anjlab libary](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/199)

```
    @Override
                public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

                    if (productId.toString().equals("sinirsiz")) {
                    //It's need to give vip status to user but is didn't.I can't see any difference on firebase database.

                       myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Kredi").setValue(Integer.toString(90000));
                        myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("VIP").setValue("Yes");
                        myRef.child("LIMITSIZLER").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("VIP").setValue("Dogrudur");
                        Toast.makeText(Buy.this, "VIP account enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnaEkran.class));
                    }  else if (productId.toString().equals("vip")) {
            //Same problem here.
                        myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Kredi").setValue(Integer.toString(900));
                        myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("VIP").setValue("Yes");
                        myRef.child("VIPBABALAR").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("VIP").setValue("Aynen");
                        Toast.makeText(Buy.this, "VIP account enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnaEkran.class));
                    }  else if (productId.toString().equals("minivip")) {
                        //And here


                        myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Kredi").setValue(Integer.toString(210));
                        myRef.child("Kullanıcılar").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Minivip").setValue("Yes");

                        myRef.child("Minivipler").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Minivip").setValue("Aynen");
                        Toast.makeText(Buy.this, "VIP account enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnaEkran.class));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingInitialized() {

                }
```

I recived payment succesfuly.I can see the play console user has purcahed to item,but they don"t get the vip.The vip function it's not triggered for whatever reason.Users has purchased the item but they don't get the status

**UPDATE**

Somebody give this code on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340020/why-android-inapp-billing-v3-library-needs-two-attempts-to-purchase) Is will work like this.Do i need to add anything ?

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```